# Django specify decimal places for FloatRangeField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model which has `FloatRangeField`

```
class Credit(models.Model):

    interest_range = FloatRangeField('Interest', null=True, blank=True)
```

And I have a model form:

```
class CreditForm(forms.ModelForm):

    interest_range = InclusiveFloatRangeField()
```

Now, I want to specify 2 fixed decimal places (Only in UI, database check is not important)

Seems `models.FloatRangeField` doesn't support `decimal_places`. And I cant't find any example in django documentation to specify decimal places for `FloatRangeField` with widgets.

django version: 2.2

Comment: Can you use DecimalRangeField instead? Seems like it's the easiest option to achieve your goal:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#decimalrangefield

Comment: @AlexK. it doesn't support `decimal_places`  too

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can pass a `fields` attribute to the `forms.DecimalRangeField` which overrides the default `base_field`:

```
interest_range = forms.DecimalRangeField(
    fields=[forms.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, required=False),
            forms.DeciamlField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, required=False)])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class LenderProfile(models.Model):
      interest_range = DecimalField('Interest',decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
```

there with **DecimalField** at the model can you select how many decimals fields you want with **decimal_places**

Comment: `DecimalField` just keeps a number, not a range.  That's not what I want.

Comment: for a range of number you need to run a validator

Comment: It's about borders, not validation. It's not a number between some range, it's range itself.